# How can i create new xaml file with c# object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a new .XAML file using a C # object.

Ex) My Object

```
public class Xaml {
    public string StringID { get; set; }
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

Ex) new.Xaml

```
 List<Xaml> objList=new List<Xaml>();
............................................
        for (int idx = 0; idx < objList.Count; ++idx) {
            //xaml ex) <System:String x:Key="objList.StringID">objList.String</System:String>
        }
```

I want to create a new file that way.

Not append, set. Just create new XAML file

Comment: Maybe you could expand on what you are intending to do with the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file like that;Its not specified for xaml, but i think you don't need that.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("xamlpath.xaml", string.Format("<System:String x:Key=\"{0}\">{1}</System:String>", objList.StringID, objList.String));
```

If file is exists, its overwritten. If not, It will create a new file.

Edit:
Or, it have a more complicated solution with better xml-xaml writing in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `XamlWriter.Save` method:

```
Xaml obj = new Xaml() { StringID = "1", String = "2" };
string xaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(obj);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\test\yourfile.xaml", xaml);
```